# Update data that is not in the same model in yii2

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a model named purchaseorder which have some purchase orders. Each purchase order have product and quantity of each product. I tried a system where I can receive the purchase order and my stock quantity get updated by purchase order quantity. I have a separate model named Stock. But I am not being able to update stock quantity using activerecords update function. Below is my code,

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);  
$item = Stock::findOne($model->order_item);


$item->quantity = $item->quantity + $model->order_item_quantity;
$item->update();
```

order_item works as product id to find the stock item that I intend to update. order_item_quantity is purchase order quantity.

It does not show any error. Does not work either. Does anybody have any idea why this is not working?

I am doing it on yii 2.0.2.

Comment: Show `rules()` method content.

Comment: Quantities of both the models are of integer type if that is what you want to know. I didn't use any custom rule that is not generated by gii tool.

Comment: Post how exactly it presented in `rules()`.